# Populate UIPickerView with PFQuery

Tags: parse-platform, uipickerview

I am trying to load a uipickerview with attributes from a column received via a PFQuery. I  think I have been able to load those items successfully and store them in an array in my viewDidLoad method using the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method. 
When logged on to the console the array(result of the query, now stored in _locationArray) looks something like the following

```
     "<Cinema:TWdBNfe6QF:(null)> {\n    Location = NY;\n    Name = A;\n}",
    "<Cinema:uCXICOaQFw:(null)> {\n    Location = DC;\n    Name = B;\n}",
    "<Cinema:TQ1F0Bj5OS:(null)> {\n    Location = LA;\n    Name = \"A, ICM\";\n}",
    "<Cinema:xiUXXYFhAl:(null)> {\n    Location = \"San Francisco\";\n    Name = C;\n}"
```

I would like to display the locations in a uipickerview.

```
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
    return [_locationArray count];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[_locationArray count]);//It never logs this count
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
    // I'm not sure how to get the location attribute
    // I get a runtime error if I try to access the _locationArray[row] element 
    }
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is iterate through the array using a for-in loop, and create a new `NSMutableArray`that you will add to. Ex:

In the header:

```
@property NSMutableArray *stringsArray;//Make sure to init in viewDidLoad
```

In .m:

```
for(PFObject *object in _locationArray)
{
   [self.stringsArray addObject:[object objectForKey:@"Location"]];

}
```

And then:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
       return [self.stringsArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see how that could work. Unfortunately I attempted to log the stringsArray but it was empty still.I'm not very familiar with threading but could it be that stringsArray never gets a chance to be populated as intended because its on the main thread while the query is run in the "background"?

Comment: @ElevenEleven Yes that is probably why. To fix this you're going to want to move the for loop I posted into the query block.

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I had to call the reloadAllComponents on the picker outlet within the query block as well

Comment: @ElevenEleven Great, glad it it worked! Reload was going to be my next suggestion lol